# PS3 Blueray 5.1 audio playback with older receiver?

Tags: ps3, audio-hardware

I'm having problems using my PS3 as a Blueray player and getting surround sound from my receiver.

First my setup:

I have both a Tivo Premier and PS3 connected to my Sony LED TV by HDMI. The Sony receiver is connected to the optical out of the TV because it doesn't support HDMI.

The Tivo has no issues passing surround sound though the TV to the receiver. I also think that if I play a DVD on the PS3 I get surround sound as well, but don't recall for sure if that's the case. When I play PS3 games I do get surround sound.

When I played both my "Man on Fire" BR and "The Social Network" BR, neither disc would the PS3 pass surround sound to the receiver, just 2.0 Dolby. Looking on the menu of "Man on Fire" it only supports TrueHD surround sound from the disc menu. From what I've gathered from some rather old posts in some A/V forums TrueHD is supposed to include DD tracks as well for older receivers like mine, but the PS3 doesn't seem to pass that on.

Anyone else have a similar setup? Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: Did you try connecting directly the optical out of the PS3 to the receiver to check if it works? On my setup, I have the optical out of the PS3 to the receiver and HDMI to the TV (you then have to set the sound settings in PS3 to output the sound through optical out).

Comment: I haven't, but I'll give that a try. It wouldn't be ideal as I would then also need to switch inputs on the reciever, but since it's only an issue when playing BR discs, and I only have 2 ATM, I could live with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have this setup (except my DVR is a DirectTv one), with an older Harmon Kardon receiver, and it works just fine.
So, there is hope.
It is almost certainly a setting combination that will get you where you want to go.
In the PS3 settings, try changing the Audio Output Format.
On your TV you may have input specific settings in the menu for audio output....my Panasonic does.

Good luck.  It can work!

Comment: Thanks. I did do some more testing and did find on the PS3 a setting that seemed to pass the 5.1 with a BR disc, but oddly only the music score. I only had time to try the 1 disc and haven't tried again.

I'll have to check the TV, I never though to check it.

Thanks